# How can I keep my timer app running in background in Expo/React Native

Tags: reactjs, timer, expo, native

On iOS devices, my timer counts down, but then crashes whenever I swipe up to open the Control Center on my iPhone. How can I keep the timer running while the app is in the background? Not only does accessing the Control Center crash the timer, it also causes any other screen of the app to crash and prevents the buttons from working thereafter. I have looked into some API such as AppState in Expo Docs, as well as some others. Anyone know the solution for this?

In essence, a user should be able to set the timer, turn the phone screen off, and the alarm should still go off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-stopwatch-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stopwatch-timer). It works very well in the background and you can custom it.